# Symmetric matrices with $\rho(A)\gg\|A\|_\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, norms, tag-removed

For a symmetric real matrix $A$, denote by $\rho(A)$ the spectral radius of $A$, and by $\sigma(A)$ the largest absolute row sum of $A$; that is, $\sigma(A)=\max_i \sum_j |a_{ij}|$, where $a_{ij}$ are the elements of $A$. We thus have $\rho(A)\le\sigma(A)$.

#### A general question:

> What can we say about $A$ given that $\sigma(A)\le K\rho(A)$ with a real $K>0$?

#### A pinpointed version (this is what I eventually need):

> Given that $\sigma(A)\le K\rho(A)$, does there necessarily exist a unit-length vector $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ (where $n$ is the order of $A$) such that $\|Ax\|\ge 0.1\rho(A)$ and $(|x_1|+\dotsb+|x_n|)\max_i|x_i|\le 10K^{10}$?

(It is not difficult to see that a unit-length vector $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with $\|Ax\|=\rho(A)$ and $(|x_1|+\dotsb+|x_n|)\max_i|x_i|\le 10K^{10}$ may *fail* to exist.)

#### An ideologically motivated restatement:

For a (not necessarily square) matrix $A\ne 0$, define the *height* of $A$ by $h(A):=\|A\|_1\|A\|_\infty/\|A\|^2$, where $\|A\|_1,\|A\|_\infty$, and $\|A\|$ are induced operator norms (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) for the definitions). Notice, that $1\le h(A)\le\sqrt{mn}$, where $m$ and $n$ are the dimensions of $A$.

If $m=n$ and $A$ is symmetric, then $\|A\|_1=\|A\|_\infty=\sigma(A)$ and $\|A\|=\rho(A)$. If $A$ is actually a vector, then $$ h(A)=\frac{(|x_1|+\dotsb+|x_n|)\max_i|x_i|}{x_1^2+\dotsb+x_n^2},$$ where $x_1,\ldots x_n$ are the coordinates of $A$. My question can be equivalently restated as follows:

> If $A$ is a symmetric real matrix with $h(A)\le K$, does there necessarily exist a vector $x$ with $\|Ax\|\ge 0.1\|A\|\|x\|$ and $h(x)\le 10K^{10}$?

The following special cases may be worth mentioning.

- if $A$ is diagonal, then the coordinate vector corresponding to the absolutely largest eigenvalue has height $1$; thus, denoting this vector by $x$, we have $\|Ax\|=\|A\|\|x\|$ and $h(x)=1$.
- if $K=1$, then $\rho(A)=\sigma(A)$. I have a complete characterization of matrices with this property, and it turns out that every principal eigenvector of such a matrix has height $1$. Hence, the assertion is true in this case, too.
- If $A$ is rank-$1$ then, in view of $A^t=A$, we have $A=\pm xx^t$ for some vector $x$. It is easy to see that in this case $\sigma(A)=h(x)\|x\|^2$, $\rho(A)=\|x\|^2$, and $x$ is a principal eigenvector of $A$. Thus, $\|Ax\|=\|A\|\|x\|$, and $h(x)=\sigma(A)/\rho(A)\le K$.

---

### Update 23.04

I doubt this will result in a major breakthrough, but I noticed recently that my original requirement $|\langle Ax,x\rangle|\ge 0.1\rho(A)$ can be relaxed to $\|Ax\|\ge 0.1\rho(A)$, and I update the problem accordingly, for a good record-keeping

Comment: This reminds me of the discrete Cheeger inequality, see Proposition 4 of http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/245b-notes-1-basic-theory-of-expander-graphs/.  Actually it may be easier to prove than discrete Cheeger, since you're working with the first eigenvalue rather than the second, and don't have to enforce any mean zero conditions.

Comment: @Terry: many thanks for the comment, but I am afraid I need more hint. Cheeger inequality relates the spectral gap with expansion properties; I am not interested in either of them. The two quantities of interest for me are the infinity norm of a matrix ($\sigma(A)=\|A\|_\infty$) and the height of a vector ($h(x)=\|x\|_1\|x\|_\infty/\|x\|^2$), none of which appear in Cheeger inequality. What direction of Cheeger inequality and exactly how can be relevant here? Thanks again!

Comment: It's not the Cheeger inequality itself which is relevant, but the _proof_ of the inequality.  In your notation, it would be to split the top eigenvector $x$ up into indicator functions $1_F$ (which have minimal neight) and split up $\langle Ax, x \rangle$ into components $\langle A1_E, 1_F \rangle$.  When E and F are very unbalanced in size, the row sum hypothesis makes these components small, so there must be a large component in which E, F have comparable size, and these are essentially your low height vectors.

Comment: The anlaogy with the Cheeger inequality is this: the spectral gap of a d-regular graph with adjacency matrix $A$ (so $\sigma(A)=d$) is essentially (up to subtraction from d) the largest eigenvalue of A after restriction to mean zero functions - the analogue of your $\rho(A)$.  The expansion constant is basically (up to subtraction from 1) the largest value of $\langle A 1_E, 1_E \rangle / |E|$ for indicator functions $1_E$ (which have height 1).

Comment: A final comment: splitting into indicator functions will give a statement similar to what you want, but not exactly: the unit vector $x$ created will have height 1, but $\|Ax\|$ will be something like $0.01 K^{-10} \rho(A)$.   It seems that you want a better bound on $\|Ax\|$ at the expense of worsening the height.  For that, you would need to decompose the eigenvector $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ instead into approximate step functions, such as those arising from restricting to indices $i$ with $t \leq |x_i| \leq \lambda t$ for some large parameter $\lambda > 0$ and some variable $t$.

Comment: @Terry: thank you very much once again, will think it over.